# Подготовка данных для обучения методом линейной регрессии

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Я новичок в машинном обучении. Мне нужно подготовить данные для метода линейной регрессии.
Мне нужно его перевести к нижнему регистру. Я знаю что это можно сделать так:

```
text.lower()
```

Но у меня вот такая ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Это ссылка на файл с которым я работаю: https://github.com/tyz910/hse-shad-ml/raw/master/10-statement-linreg/salary-train.csv

Comment: это ошибка не из этой части кода ) покажите, где вы из DataFrame делаете text?

Comment: А скажите, зачем вам тестовый файл -  все равно в каком регистре  -  для задачи построения модели линейной регрессии?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно применять метод к специфичным колонкам датафрейма.
В вашем случае:

```
df["FullDescription"] = df["FullDescription"].str.lower()
```

Обратите внимание на модификатор `str` после названия колонки.

Если у вас таких столбцов много и вы не хотите каждый переводить вручную, можете сделать таким образом:

```
df.select_dtypes(include='object').apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```